# iTextSharp & Windows

Tags: pdf, printing, itext

Is there a way to convert from iTextSharp `Document` class to `System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument` (in c#) so i can give print facilities to user?

thanks

Comment: don't know the answer.  Did you consider an XPS document instead of PDF?  You wouldn't need iTextSharp in that case.

Comment: I need to generate a pdf with other invoice information, XPS document is not an option for my application. thankyou

Answer (score 2):

iText can read, parse and write pdf files. It cannot render them.

Look at some of the commercial libraries that can do this, or something like GhostScript.

Comment: I have to show the user printpreview, settings and print options for that document. Does ghostscript does that?

Comment: No. If you have to do this, why not simply use the Adobe activex control and skip the System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument? Here is how (in Windows Forms) http://thedotnet.com/nntp/396093/showpost.aspx